# Sending an array via email in Java

Tags: java, arrays, jakarta-mail

I have an array which I would like to send via Email. So far, I have been able to send it successfully in the [Value1, Value2, Value3] format using the code below:

```
    public static void EmailInfo(String[] args) {
                String from = Username;
                String pass = Password;
                String[] to = { recep}; 
                String subject = "Subject Header";
                String body = Arrays.toString(Retrieve.CalcResults);


                sendFromGMail(from, pass, to, subject, body);
            }
//Some more code here

message.setSubject(subject);
                message.setText(body);
                Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
                transport.connect(host, from, pass);
                transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
                transport.close();
```

As you can see I had to put my entire Array `CalcResults` to a new String then pass that on as the message text. When I make `body` an array, I get an error in the line `message.setText(body[])` saying this method is not applicable for the arguments (String[]).

How can I work around this?

Comment: I think this tutorial helps http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-send-an-email-in-java.html

Comment: I have recieved many emails, but none of them have ever contained an array.

Comment: why are you setting the body to an array? what's the desired result for this email?

Comment: I just want the values contained in the array to be sent as an email. So let's say I have an array containing `[apples, oranges, peaches, tomatoes]`, I'd like to send an email that says "apples, oranges, peaches, tomatoes".

Comment: So `StringUtils.join(myArray, ", ")`

Comment: I'm not using Spring, just the JavaMail API. Is there something similar for JavaMail?

Comment: This isn't a JavaMail problem.  It's just a string formatting problem.  Create and format the string however you want to, then use the string as the content of the mail message.

Answer (score 0):

message.setText accepts a String.
You have tried to send a String[]. To Java this is a different thing.

I would recommend creating a method that accepts a String[] and returns a String
or using something like Jackson to turn the String[] into a JSON string.